# Combining Like Objects by Date in JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array:

```
var objArray = [
    { num: 1, date: '1/12/2017' },
    { num: 3, date: '1/12/2017' },
    { num: 7, date: '1/12/2017' },
    { num: 1, date: '1/13/2018' },
    { num: 3, date: '1/16/2018' },
    { num: 4, date: '1/16/2018' }
   ];
```

I want to combine those with same dates so that the output array looks like this:

```
var outputArr = [
    { num: 11, date: '1/12/2017' },
    { num: 1,  date: '1/13/2018' },
    { num: 7,  date: '1/16/2018' }
   ];
```

I'm adding all `num` with similar dates and creating a single new object.

I have a very large dataset of objects like this so I'm trying to reduce the amount of processing time for this.

I've got the arrays sorted by date so that it mirrors `objArray`.

For loops seems cumbersome since I'm taking the first date in the array and checking every other element in the array a la the following pseudo-code:

```
var newArr = [];
for(i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < objArray.length; j++) {
        var tempArr = [];
        // check every date manually
        // add similar to new array
        tempArr.push({ similar items });
    }
    newArr.push(tempArr):
}

// Do another couple loops to combine those like arrays into another array
```

There has to be a more elegant way to perform this than running multiple for loops.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use `Array.reduce()` to create a map and group values by date, `Object.values()` on the map will give you the desired output value:

```js
let arr = [ { num: 1, date: '1/12/2017' }, { num: 3, date: '1/12/2017' }, { num: 7, date: '1/12/2017' }, { num: 1, date: '1/13/2018' }, { num: 3, date: '1/16/2018' }, { num: 4, date: '1/16/2018' } ];
   
let result = Object.values(arr.reduce((a, {num, date})=>{
  if(!a[date])
    a[date] = Object.assign({},{num, date});
   else
    a[date].num += num;
  return a;
 },{}));
 console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using lodash,

```
// Aggregate num from unique dates
var g = _.groupBy(objArray,'date')
Object.keys(g).map(k=>({num:g[k].reduce((a,c)=>c.num+a,0),date:k}))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var objArray = [
    { num: 1, date: '1/12/2017' },
    { num: 3, date: '1/12/2017' },
    { num: 7, date: '1/12/2017' },
    { num: 1, date: '1/13/2018' },
    { num: 3, date: '1/16/2018' },
    { num: 4, date: '1/16/2018' }
   ];

let outputArr = Array.from(objArray.reduce((acc, obj)=>{
  acc.set(obj.date, (acc.get([obj.date]) || 0) + obj.num);
  return acc;
}, new Map()))
.map(kv=>({num: kv[1], date: kv[0]}))

console.log(outputArr);
```

gives:

```
[ { num: 11, date: '1/12/2017' },
  { num: 1, date: '1/13/2018' },
  { num: 7, date: '1/16/2018' } ]
```

Comment: This seems to create an object rather than an array of objects.

Comment: @razorsyntax uses `Object.entries(result).map((item) => {return {num: item[1], date: item[0]}} )` to convert that result to array.

Comment: Yes, it was wrong. Now it uses Map - and is even shorter

Answer (score 1):

You could also remove the if statements and use a Set if you wanted to be even more declarative.

```
var objArray = [
    { num: 1, date: '1/12/2017' },
    { num: 3, date: '1/12/2017' },
    { num: 7, date: '1/12/2017' },
    { num: 1, date: '1/13/2018' },
    { num: 3, date: '1/16/2018' },
    { num: 4, date: '1/16/2018' }
];
var mSet = new Set(objArray.map(d => d.date));
return Array.from(mSet).map(d => {
    return
    { 
        date: d,
        sum: (objArray
            .filter(o => o.date === d)
            .map(n => n.num)
            .reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0))
    }
);
```

This returns:

```
[{ date: 1/12/2017, sum: 11},
{ date: 1/13/2018, sum: 1 },
{ date: 1/16/2018, sum: 7 }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way. It's more verbose, but if you're just starting out it might be easier to understand as opposed to using array methods like reduce().

```
objArray = [
    { num: 1, date: '1/12/2017' },
    { num: 3, date: '1/12/2017' },
    { num: 7, date: '1/12/2017' },
    { num: 1, date: '1/13/2018' },
    { num: 3, date: '1/16/2018' },
    { num: 4, date: '1/16/2018' }
]


function combineObj(data) {
    let validator= new Set();
    let combinedArr = [];
    let numCount = 0;
    
    // Create a list of unique properties to match against:
    data.forEach((e) => validator.add(e.date));

    // For each value in the validator, create a new object in a new array 
    // and add the unique values from the validator to the respective property:
    validator.forEach((e) => {
        combinedArr.push({
            num: 0,
            date: e
        });
    })

    // Lastly, for each object in the combinedArr, use a counter to sum up the total values of each property
    // as you loop through your data:
    combinedArr.forEach((e) => {
        numCount = 0;
        data.forEach((ee) => {
            if (e.date === ee.date) {
                numCount += ee.num;
                e.num = numCount;
            }
        })
    })

    return combinedArr;
}
```

Returns:

```
[
  { num: 11, date: '1/12/2017' },
  { num: 1, date: '1/13/2018' },
  { num: 7, date: '1/16/2018' }
]
```